# Install JavaScript plugin in Android Studio

Tags: plugins, android-studio

I'm running Android Studio version 0.3.7 on OS X 10.9. When I opened a JavaScript file I received a prompt saying: `Plugin supporting files with *.js are found` with 2 options: `install plugins` and `ignore plugins`. When I click the install option, a new `Choose plugins to install or Enable` window pops up, but it's empty, and only "nothing to show" is written. Has anyone experienced this? Is there a way to manually search and install these JavaScript plugins?

Answer (score 2):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25109551/4028484 for a Git repo with appropriate settings for syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue on Gentoo GNU/Linux running Android Studio 0.4.0.

If you go to File -> Settings -> IDE Settings -> Plugins -> Brows Repositories, you should see a long list. Setting the category to Javascript returns 10 plugins for me, but none of them look to provide core support (syntax highlighting etc).

I think perhaps the IDE is finding a plugin and attempting to load a filtered list that's supposed to only show the one plugin it found, but the lists then don't return it probably because it isn't compatible with the current IDE version.